# Why am I getting this htaccess error

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I have a rule in my htaccess file to remove a www subdomain like so:

```
<IfModule mod_suphp.c>
    suPHP_ConfigPath /home/myusername/php.ini
        <Files php.ini>
            order allow,deny    
            deny from all   
        </Files>
</IfModule>

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.mysite\.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://mysite.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

When I try to go to www.mysite.com it tries to send me to http://mysite.com/public_html/

What's causing this and how would I fix it? If it helps I'm using a shared hosting plan on hostgator.

Comment: I think your escaping of the `.` (dot) is confusing the parser - have you tried without the escaping?

Comment: @Lix: yeah with the same results

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IIRC, the HostGator document root for `userX` is `/home/userX/public_html`, not `/home/userX`, so the symptoms that you are describing are what I'd expect unless of course your trying to do go to `/home/userX/public_html/public_html` which might be an artefact of not specifying a

```
RewriteBase /
```

After the `RewriteEngine On`